# Why does dataframe object convert to TimeSeries Object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a data frame.  With multiple columns (e.g. 'A', 'B')
Using the following code, I want to make a new dataframe based on just one column:

```
df2 = df1['A']
```

However, when I do so, the data frame is suddenly converted to TimeSeries

```
In [5] print type (df2)<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Very very odd...can anyone explain to me why this happens...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df1['A']` returns a Series. `df1[['A']]` returns a DataFrame.

Slicing behaves differently depending on the type of object you pass between the
brackets.

If you slice a DataFrame,`df`, with a string, the DataFrame tries to find the
string in `df.columns` and if it succeeds, returns the column as a Series.

If you slice `df` with a list (of strings), then the DataFrame tries to find
each of the strings in `df.columns` and if it succeeds, returns the columns as a
new DataFrame. If the list happens to only contain one string, then you get a
DataFrame with just one column.

---

When slicing is used in an **assignment**, `df['B'] = xyz` calls
`df.__setitem__('B', xyz)`. The DataFrame's `__setitem__` was implemented to
modify `df` itself. The assignment does not return a value, but it does modify
`df` in place.

When slicing is used in an **expression**, `df[xyz]` calls
`df.__getitem__(xyz)`. The DataFrame's `__getitem__` method returns a different
type of object depending on the type of `xyz`.

Comment: aah, ok. I have been using the syntax `'df2['B']' = df2['B']` to assign a new column in an already **existing** dataframe. In that scenario, the data frame, remained a data frame. 
But when using the above syntax to assign the values to a new variable, it is automatically converted to a Series...

Comment: When slicing is used in an **assignment**, `df2['B'] = xyz`  calls `df2.__setitem__('B', xyz)`. The DataFrame's `__setitem__` was implemented to modify `df2` itself. The assignment does not return a value, but it does modify `df2` in place. When slicing is used in an **expression**, `df2[xyz]` calls `df2.__getitem__(xyz)`. The DataFrame's `__getitem__` method returns a different type of object depending on the type of `xyz`.

Comment: @unutbu, the slicing is very well explained. It would be worth adding into the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `df1['A']` is a Pandas series therefore assigning it to df2 will result a pandas series.

`pandas.DataFrame(df.A)` - Will create a new pandas dataframe